# solution of an algebraic equation with integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$  has an infinite number of solutions when $x,y,z$ are integers.

I started from specific cases.

Comment: Expanding the right side may help.

Comment: Did you find any solutions, Joshua?

Comment: @AfronPie no, here are some  positive xyz         21         7        14   gcd  7 \\  
       100        55        85   gcd  5 \\  
       105        60        75   gcd  15 \\  
       125        75       100   gcd  25 \\  
       184       115       161   gcd  23 \\  
       260       175       205   gcd  5 \\  
       265       155       250   gcd  5 \\  
       385       275       330   gcd  55 \\  
       497       259       266   gcd  7 \\  
       845       650       715   gcd  65 \\  
       873       679       776   gcd  97 \\  
       989       736       943   gcd  23 \\

Comment: If $x^2+y^2+z^2=d(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$, then $(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2=(dx-dy)(dy-dz)(dz-dx)$.

Comment: Generalizing  Gerry Myerson's comment, if $x^2+y^2+z^2
=d^a(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)
$ then $d^ax, d^ay, d^az$ is a solution. Other combinations of exponents don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Let $r$ be odd, then $(r+2)^2+r^2+(r+1)^2$ is even, so it is a multiple of $((r+2)-r)(r-(r+1))((r+1)-(r+2))=2$. The quotient is $d=(3r^2+6r+5)/2$. Then $x=d(r+2)$, $y=dr$, $z=d(r+1)$ works.

Of course, there are many more. E.g., let $b=a+1$, $c=a+3$. Then $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=6$. If $a$ is even, then $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is divisible by 2, and if $a-1$ is divisible by $3$, then so is $a^2+b^2+c^2$, so if $a=6r-2$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=108r^2-24r+6=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)s$ where $s=18r^2-4r+1$. So, $x=(6r-2)s$, $y=(6r-1)s$, $z=(6r+1)s$ is a solution for $r=1,2,3,\dots$.